# Executing dotnet CLI tool fails on Mac (.NET 6/Mac OS Big Sur)

Tags: macos, .net-core, .net-6.0

I developed a simple .NET 6 CLI tool that inserts license headers to any .cs files where it is missing. I packed the tool, pushed it to my local feed, then installed to my local `$HOME/.nuget/packages/` using `--global`.

When I execute the tool, .net says it cannot find a compatible framework version.

```
It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
The framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '6.0.0' was not found.
  - The following frameworks were found:
      3.1.15 at [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
      5.0.6 at [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

You can resolve the problem by installing the specified framework and/or SDK.
```

Running `dotnet --list-runtimes` outputs the following:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.0 [/Users/dan/.dotnet/6.0.0/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.0 [/Users/dan/.dotnet/6.0.0/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

This is where I extracted the .net binaries when I installed .NET 6. The other locations in `/usr/local/share/dotnet` are previous installations. I added the `DOTNET_ROOT` environment variable as noted [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/troubleshoot-usage-issues). Why can't the dotnet tool find my installation path?

Answer (score 0):

Because it is the responsibility of the Global tool developer to add .NET 6 runtime to its runtime list,

```
<TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp3.1;net5.0;net6.0</TargetFrameworks>
```

https://github.com/obfuscar/obfuscar/blob/2.2.32/GlobalTools/GlobalTools.csproj#L5

If the original developer cannot help you quick enough, try to install the runtimes (5.0.6 for example) it asks for and you are good to go.

Comment: I'm the tool developer - and I have the target framework set to `net6.0`.

Comment: Then where is your package on NuGet.org? Yours must look similar to Obfuscar Global Tool on FuGet, https://www.fuget.org/packages/Obfuscar.GlobalTool/2.2.32, or it will fail like that.

Comment: You don’t have to push a tool package to nuget.org to install it locally, you just have to push it to your local package directory.